# Ошибка с PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Здравствуйте. Проблема такая: отправляю письма в html формате c помощью phpmailer, а мне на экран выводится кучу разное информации об отправлении, хотя письма доходят отлично. При этом если оставить только пару тегов, сообщение не выводиться. Вот код отправления

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(false);
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host = $smtp['host'];
                $mail->SMTPDebug = $smtp['debug'];
                $mail->SMTPAuth = $smtp['auth'];
                $mail->Port = $smtp['port'];
                $mail->SMTPSecure = $smtp['secure'];
                $mail->CharSet = $smtp['charset'];
                $mail->Username = $smtp['username'];
                $mail->Password = $smtp['password'];
                $mail->addAddress("$email", "$firstname $lastname");
                $mail->setFrom('...', '...');
                $mail->Subject = htmlspecialchars('Подтверждение почтового адреса');
                $text = file_get_contents(MAIL_PATH."/mail_registration.html");
                $text = str_replace(['%name%', '%code%'], [$firstname, $code], $text);
                $mail->Body = $text;
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->send();
```

В файле mail_registration.html только теги p и пару div

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить строку на такую:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
```